# ApplicationHost.CreateApplicationHost and SignalR

Tags: asp.net, signalr, owin

I use System.Web.ApplicationHost.CreateApplicationHost to run a website I have without putting it under IIS.
Everything works fine, the website runs great.

IU wanted to add to the website some SignalR functionality, but when I do this and run the website via my own application host, the Owin startup class is never get hit.
When I run the application via IISexpress, the Owin startup class gets hit.

My question is how can I make the signalR work (make Owin startup class hit) when using my own webserver host with System.Web.ApplicationHost.CreateApplicationHost?

Comment: possible duplicate of [SignalR and SelfHosting ASPNet app](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20935502/signalr-and-selfhosting-aspnet-app)

Answer (score 0):

What version of SignalR are you using? The OWIN startup class is only used in version 2.

Are you invoking the Startup.cs class from your web.config file? The recommended method is to use an attribute on the Startup.cs class instead, since web.config isn't used for self-host.

Here's an example, from the Getting Started tutorial:

```
[assembly: OwinStartup(typeof(SignalRChat.Startup))]
namespace SignalRChat
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            // Any connection or hub wire up and configuration should go here
            app.MapSignalR();
        }
    }
}
```