# SignalR and SelfHosting ASPNet app

Tags: asp.net, signalr, owin

I have an ASPnet webapplication that uses SignalR, it works fine under IIS.

When I try to self host the  ASP.NET webapplication with System.Web.ApplicationHost.CreateApplicationHost, The signalR functionality is gone.

From debugging, I see that the OWin Startup class is never hit.

Does anyone have a clue why? From what I understand, the CreateApplicationHost is just hosting the application outside of IIS, but it still runs through the ASP.NET pipeline, So, I don't understand why Owin startup and SignalR wont work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When hosted inside of ASP.NET, OWIN-based applications require the IIS integrated pipeline.  CreateApplicationHost forces use of the ASP.NET classic pipeline.

If you want to self-host, use the HttpListener-based OWIN host rather than trying to self-host ASP.NET directly.

Comment: Ho can I use HttpListener-based OWIN host to run a website with regular aspx files

Comment: You can't.  What is your exact scenario; why is IIS-based hosting (which is generally required for newer ASP.NET features like WebSockets) insufficient for your needs?

Answer (score 1):

For instructions on self-hosting SignalR, see the following tutorial:

http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/signalr-20/getting-started-with-signalr-20/tutorial-signalr-20-self-host